# Can we add options to the Flag reasons?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

Under Flags>Closing>Off-Topic here are the options:

> Trivia questions are off-topic; we're not trying to duplicate IMDB. See: Should movie trivia questions be closed?
>
> Identification questions must contain sufficient detail to be answerable. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X-Questions.
>
> Questions about current events are off-topic because these items are rapidly changing and do not have a definitive answer. For more information, see our FAQ.
>
> Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with movies or tv)
>
> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33829/movie-license-for-paying-audience) about film licensing is not any of these options.

It's certainly appropriate for the "Closing" option:

> off-topic because... This question does not appear to be about movies or tv **within the scope defined in the help center**.

Because that is the case, it's not within the scope of what M&TV deals with but:

> It's not Trivia.
>
> It's not an ID question
>
> It's not about Current Events.
>
> It **is** a question about movies & TV, so it's not "blatantly off topic".
>
> There's not anywhere else to ask it.

We need an option that says "About Movies & TV but not within the scope defined in the help center." Or, at the very least, we need an "Other" option.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably missing something, since that is usually the case, but... we already have an "Other" option?

This only appears when you have enough rep to close vote, and one you can close vote you can no longer flag for closure. This would make the answer to getting free text custom close reasons "get more rep".

[image]

Regarding adding an additional permanent option... Do these questions pop up frequently enough to justify an additional permanent entry adding to our site specific custom closure reasons?

Comment: This is **ONLY** for people with the close-vote privilege.

Comment: ...and *that's* what I missed.

Comment: Afterall that screenshot even *is* from the close voting dialog and not from the flagging dialog at all. So even without this admittedly confusing fact that users see different versions of the flagging dialog this screenshot would have been irrelevant for the matter.

Comment: @nap same box for flagging closed and closures when you have the the rep to close. That you could've tested yourself...

Comment: @Flyk Sure, now we know. Doesn't seem to be adressed in the answer, though. *I* certainly could have tested that (and I have), but that doesn't give the screenshot relevance for the answer so much when the question is about flagging.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson They aren't actually the same... The close vote one doesn't have the "should be on another SE site" option, actually. The one you posted on the Chat shows that option still. http://i.imgur.com/9asZa8K.png